# Card.js - can't find a numberInput in your form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've seen some other posts here but nothing in them has helped me (or their solution is something I've already done).

My card does show up, but in the console there are the following errors:

```
Card can't find a numberInput in your form.
Card can't find a expiryInput in your form.
Card can't find a cvcInput in your form.
Card can't find a nameInput in your form.
```

I am currently using jquery.card.js, the most recent which I downloaded from here (https://github.com/jessepollak/card) and pulled from the "dist" folder.

This is the section of my form related specifically to the card:

```
<div class="box-body" style="">
    <div class='card-wrapper'></div>
    <!-- CSS is included via this JavaScript file -->

    <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control" id="number">
    <input type="text" name="expiry" class="form-control"/>
    <input type="text" name="cvc" class="form-control"/>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>
 </div>
```

And here is my setup for the card:

```
<script>
    $('form').card({
    // a selector or DOM element for the container
    // where you want the card to appear
    container: '.card-wrapper', // *required*

    // all of the other options from above


            formatting: true, // optional - default true

            // Strings for translation - optional
            messages: {
                validDate: 'valid\ndate', // optional - default 'valid\nthru'
                monthYear: 'mm/yyyy', // optional - default 'month/year'
            },

            // Default placeholders for rendered fields - optional
            placeholders: {
                number: '•••• •••• •••• ••••',
                name: 'Full Name',
                expiry: '••/••',
                cvc: '•••'
            },

            formSelectors: {
                numberInput: 'input[name="number"]', // optional — default input[name="number"]
                expiryInput: 'input[name="expiry"]', // optional — default input[name="expiry"]
                cvcInput: 'input[name="cvc"]', // optional — default input[name="cvc"]
                nameInput: 'input[name="name"]' // optional - defaults input[name="name"]
            },

            // if true, will log helpful messages for setting up Card
            debug: true // optional - default false
});
</script>
```

As I said before, the image of the card does appear so I know parts of this script are in fact working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to change the line: `$('form').card({` to the form's specific ID. It works now.